# Filtering Results of a Regression Output + Exporting the Subsequent Data Frame to CSV/XLS/XLSX

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, regression

My question is twofold. First, I was wondering if there was a way to filter the results of a regression analysis similar to the way it can be done in SPSS.

I've seen this question has been asked here before, but I have been getting confused on whether the data needs to be filtered before you run the regression, or if there is code you add to the lm/glm command to get the results to filter. For example, my data looks like this:

```
country  year  number of events
1        2016  208
1        2017  98
2        2016  107
2        2017  316
3        2016  509
3        2017  421
```

and I would like my output to sort the results of the regression by country so it looks like this:

```
country  var coef  stde
1         1   xxx   xxx
1         2   xxx   xxx
1         3   xxx   xxx
2         1   xxx   xxx
2         2   xxx   xxx
2         3   xxx   xxx
```

What would be the best method to do this?

Second, I was wondering if there was a way to export a data frame with this data to an Excel format so it could be used in another program like ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

df <- data.frame(country = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), 
                 year = c(2016,2017,2016,2017,2016,2017), 
                 number_of_events = c(208, 98, 107, 316, 509, 421))

colnames(df)[3] <- "number of events"
```

You have to filter before the regression, otherwise `` lm`() `` will run all rows. You can do this using `group_by` from `dplyr`. You group by the country and then pipe the filtered data into `lm()`. I don't know what your regression formula is so I've just regressed number of events on year. Then you can use the `tidy()` function from the `broom` package to create a dataframe of coefficients. You can inspect the dataframe to drop the elements you don't want. Exporting a dataframe to excel is easy using the `write.csv()` function.

```r
df_fit <- df %>% group_by(country) %>%
  do(fiitedmod = lm(`number of events` ~ year , data = .))

df_coef <- tidy(df_fit, fiitedmod)
df_coef

write.csv(df_coef, "data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```